# error interface based on a segment control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm creating an interface based on a segment control that goes to control five different view containers. but I'm stuck when the app starts makes me mistake in the

[image]

I have no idea what the error is I can't identify it
line any idea ??

could someone help me solve this problem please

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fifth: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fourth: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var third: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var second: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var first: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SegmentOutLet: UISegmentedControl!
    var views:[UIView]=[]
    var counter=0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        views=[first,second,third,fourth,fifth]
        //Qua il gesto per effettuare lo Swipe
        SegmentOutLet.selectedSegmentIndex=counter
        let swipeleft=UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlegesture(gesture:)))
        swipeleft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeleft)
        let swiperight=UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlegesture(gesture:)))
        swiperight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swiperight)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(first)
    }
    @objc func handlegesture(gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        ///----------------------
        if counter>=0 && counter < views.count{
            if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
                if counter != 0{
                    counter=counter-1
                    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(views[counter])
                    SegmentOutLet.selectedSegmentIndex=counter
                }
            }
            ///--------------------
            if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
                if counter != views.count-1{
                    counter=counter+1
                    SegmentOutLet.selectedSegmentIndex=counter
                    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(views[counter])
                }
            }
           ///----------------
        }
    }
    @IBAction func SegmentActiobn(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(views[sender.selectedSegmentIndex])
        counter=SegmentOutLet.selectedSegmentIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: That error *appears* to indicate a mismatch in your `@IBOutlet` connections. Try adding each one to the array on a separate line: `views.append(first)` then next line `views.append(second)` and so on. See if the error occurs for one of them.